# forEachPartition works but not mapPartition

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a spark streaming application that read a Kafka stream and inserts data to a database.

This is the code snippet

```
eventDStream.foreachRDD { (rdd, time) =>
      val offsetRanges = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges

      // First example that works
      val accumulator = streamingContext.sparkContext.longAccumulator
      rdd.foreachPartition { records =>
        val count = Consumer.process(records)
        accumulator.add(count)
      }
      println(s"accumulated $accumulator.value")
      // do the same but aggregate count, does not work
      val results = rdd.mapPartitions(records => Consumer.processIterator(records))
      val x = results.fold(0)(_ + _)
      println(x)
      eventDStream.asInstanceOf[CanCommitOffsets].commitAsync(offsetRanges)
    }
```

In the first part, I used the `foreachPartition` with an accumulator to count the number of successful inserts

In the second part, I computed an `RDD[Int]` the represents the number of successful inserts in each `RDD`and aggregate the result using the `fold` function

But the second part always prints 0 and the first part always do exactly what I want.

Can you show me why?

Thanks

Comment: Difficult to say as implementations of `Consumer.process` and `Consumer. processIterator ` are not known. But if you change the latter part to `val results = rdd.mapPartitions(records => Iterator.single(Consumer.process(records)))` it should produce the same results

Comment: Actually the `Consumer.processIterator ` uses the `process` function but convert to a List and then `toIterator`. So it must do the same thing